# SCSS - usage of image files with relative path are not working

Tags: sass, webpack-4, sass-loader

I have the following 4 files:

```
/src/images/image.png
/src/scss/main.scss
/src/scss/test/test.scss
/src/js/entry.js
```

In `main.scss` I have the following code:

```
 @import './test/test.scss';
```

In 'test.scss' I have the following code:

```
 .test {
    background-image: url(../../images/image.png);
 }
```

And in 'entry.js' I have the following code:

```
 import './../scss/main.scss'
```

When I try to build this project with webpack, I get an error, that the `image.png` file can not be resolved. It appears, that when I build this project, `test.scss` thinks that it's relative folder is `/src/scss/`. If I change `../../images/image.png` to `../images/image.png` everything works correctly.

Is there any way to tell `webpack` or `sass-loader` to threat every imported file, as a separate file, and always use paths relative to the currently opened file? Or is there any way to specify paths from the root folder of my application (`/src` in this case)?

Comment: You can study this https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/46

Comment: You can get information about this specific issue in this https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#problems-with-url